# Ripple noise from TPS75633

Tags: voltage-regulator

We have used [TPS75633KC](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS756) on our custom board. The supply to the regulator is provided from a common point, to which different boards have been connected. We are observing heavy noise introduced in the output and when we isolated the custom board by providing supply from an external source, the noise in the output was absent completely.

We also used an oscilloscope and high impedance probe to measure the ripple noise and it measures around 600mv.

We followed the same application circuit mentioned on the datasheet of the regulator.

We have used 1uf and 10uf at the input and 47uf and 0.1uf at the output. These Ceramic capacitors.

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Take another look at datasheet page 19 (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps756.pdf#page=19), I think your problem rely on stability issues because of your output capacitance.

It does say to use a minimum of 47uF AND a minimum of 200mOhm ESR.
They even give you a formula and stability chart to go along.

So let's assume you've used a common 1206 MLCC 47uF 16V like: https://product.tdk.com/en/search/capacitor/ceramic/mlcc/info?part_no=C3216X5R1C476M160AB

Click on the TDK link and scroll-down to take a look at the "ESR" chart (you can even overlay your mouse to read data points from the chart), it is shown that capacitor is under **80mOhm** at 1kHz.
Now take a look at the "DC Bias Characteristic" chart. Assuming your LDO outputs a standard 3.3V, the actual capacitance is about half the initial value (~23uF).

Now do you meet the requirements stated in the datasheet? I believe the answer is no.

What can you do about it? Well the answer is still in the datasheet:
"Solid tantalum electrolytic and aluminum electrolytic capacitors are all suitable, provided they meet the requirements described in this section."

And so why a different type of capacitor than MLCC? In brief, MLCC have very low ESR values which is generally great for decoupling but certain regulator design stability rely on higher ESR output values and here MLCC won't help much.
Aluminum electrolytic and tantalum capacitors, other than having much lower voltage derating than MLCC, do have higher ESR than MLCC.

In conclusion you may want to buy few of these (or any equivalent) to replace your 47uF MLCC output capacitor:
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/w-rth-elektronik/860080372001/732-8989-1-ND/5728932

Let us know the result!

Comment: In some designs, people add a small resistor in series with the MLCC to meet the required minimum ESR. That could be another option, instead of changing the output cap type.

Comment: Problem is that I have used a 0805 package footprint on my custom board for output capacitors.

Comment: @dim You're totally right! Judging by the question, I did not want to introduce this possibility to keep it as simple as possible. It is definitely a more tricky path than just a good old electrolytic, I am personally inclined to say to consider only for space constraint (eg. can't use aluminum electrolytic) or tight budget (eg. can't use tantalum/polymer).

Comment: @MightyBeard007 I gave you an example path, I made a lot of assumption (clearly stated) along the way because I couldn't find any information in your initial post. Please follow the logic using the actual capacitor you've used and tell us what you find out.

Comment: I am thinking of using higher capacitor values(more than 47uf) and try once

Comment: @MightyBeard007 Depending how you increase the capacitor value, you may not leave the instability zone. For instance adding more 47uF MLCC in parallel wouldn't help.

Comment: Not the same regulator but it is helpful https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=21&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjf94r0uK_mAhW5wjgGHW0wAfE4FBAWMAB6BAgFEAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Fcn%2Flit%2Fpdf%2Fslva549&usg=AOvVaw2e5kXMELSmgCegJYMtFqNj

Comment: @MightyBeard007 Have you read the datasheet for this other regulator? (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps84259.pdf#page=14) It suggest only using ceramic capacitors for output decoupling. You're are in a TOTALLY different case, you can NOT rely on this other application note to solve your issue. I know it is frustrating but you won't solve this stability issue with adding more ceramic caps in parallel as you are effectively decreasing the equivalent ESR.